# How is taking an independent variable to be a function of another independent variable correct logic?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

While proving the implicit differentiation theorem the lecturer (on an Youtube lecture series based on Multivariable Calculus) used the following method:

Suppose $$f(x,y)=C$$ (where $C$ is a constant). Now $x$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ **can also be thought of** as a function of $x$.

Thus, differentiating w.r.t $x$

we get $$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}=0\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\partial f/\partial x}{\partial f/\partial y}$$

The result is of course correct, but I don't feel taking $y$ to be a function of $x$ is logically correct. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm confused with your question. Why **can't** $y$ be a function of $x$?

Comment: @Mattos Umm, isn't $y$ an independent variable? We consider $x$ and $y$ to be independent variables in $f(x,y)=C$. How can an independent variable be a function of another independent variable?

Comment: If you are trying to prove the implicit function theorem itself, then yes, I agree it's not reasonable to start by assuming $y = y(x)$ and then compute a formula for $y'$. Instead, start by parameterising $x$ and $y$ by $t$, then compute $df/dt$ etc.

Comment: For example take the equation $Sin(xy)=1$. Then $xy=\pi / 2$ or $y(x)=\frac{\pi}{2x}$

Comment: We can parameterize the function $f(x,y)=C$ in the form of $x=g(t)$ and $y=h(t)$, such that $f(g(t),h(t))=C$

$$\therefore \frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}=0\implies \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\partial f/\partial x}{\partial f/\partial y}$$